# How can I use docker-compose locally after setting up a docker-machine host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I setup docker-machine to administer a site on digital ocean. That all worked nicely, but now I can't use `docker-compose` locally: it starts the docker containers on the remote server. Is there a way to specify not to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `docker-machine` it will set your `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable, that's where your `docker` client will point to and run all the commands. You either need to do `eval $(docker-machine env -u)` to unset the environment variables back to your local, or just export `DOCKER_HOST` to point back to your local before you run `docker-compose`.

Comment: So just set `DOCKER_HOST` to `localhost`?

Comment: If you set it to nothing (`export DOCKER_HOST=`) then Docker will use the local daemon by default.